# How to CRUD data in mongoose without data modeling

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, crud

i was searching  internet for 2 days now and did not find any answer,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const channelsSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        stateName: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'A state must have a name'],
            unique: true,
            index:true
        },
        id: {
            type:String
        },
        Name: {
            type:String
        },
        **anyThing: [Object]
    },
    { strict: false }
);

const Channels = mongoose.model('Channels', channelsSchema);

module.exports = Channels;
```

is there any way to **anything accept anything?

note: its not a big project and im not worried about the security. it runs only localy

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `{strict: false}` as second argument to the Schema to achieve this.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const channelsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({}, {strict: false})
const Channels = mongoose.model('Channels', channelsSchema);
module.exports = Channels;
```